# I cant get the expected output in my code (signup login system)

Tags: python, output

Hi i'm new in python and in programming in general ! i tried to make a login system with python but it doesnt seem to be working as i expect 
the problem is even if i enter false login informations at the end the program will print login successful instead of printing incorrect username or password
NOTE : i'm not trying to make real login system it's just some practice form what i learned

```
signup_username = ""
signup_password = ""
login_username = ""
login_password = ""
false_login_info = False
def signup() :
  signup_username = input("Choose your username :")
  signup_password = input("Choose your password :")

def login() :
  login_username = input("Enter username :")
  login_password = input("Enter password :")
signup()
print("Signup successful")
login()
if login_username != signup_username or login_password != signup_password :
  print("Incorrect username or password")
else :
  print("login successful")
```

EXPECTED Result :
1) if login informations are same as signup infos i should get :
- Login successful
2) if login informations are NOT same as signup infos i shoul get :
- Incorrect username or password 
ACTUAL Result :
in both cases the program will print login successful

Comment: This is a scope issue. `signup_username` inside and outside of the function blocks are not the same thing.

Comment: @roganjosh how can i fix this

Comment: An aside; if this were a real login system and you intended to make use of `false_login_info = False`, the default position should be `True`. That way, if anything goes wrong that you didn't foresee, you don't end up logging the user in by default.

Comment: Also, I would recommend reading [mcve] and [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/); they're both useful for learning how to solve the problem faster yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the values from your functions. The names defined inside the function are not the same as those that exist outside of the function. In this case, I have appended `x` to the names in the global scope to differentiate them from the ones inside the function to hopefully make it clearer. I could have used the same names both inside the function and outside; it wouldn't have made a difference. You can see more [here](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html).

There is no need to "initialise" the variables as empty strings before the function call. Instead, we'll just create them in the function, `return` them, and then *unpack* them into the variables ending in `x`.

```
false_login_info = False # You never use this

def signup() :
    signup_username = input("Choose your username :")
    signup_password = input("Choose your password :")
    return signup_username, signup_password

def login() :
    login_username = input("Enter username :")
    login_password = input("Enter password :")
    return login_username, login_password


signup_usernamex, signup_passwordx = signup()
print("Signup successful")

login_usernamex, login_passwordx = login()

if login_usernamex != signup_usernamex or login_passwordx != signup_passwordx:
    print("Incorrect username or password")
else :
    print("login successful")
```

Comment: thx for your help in this case i go my expected output i'll try to understand the changes you have made  i dont seem to really understand what the return statment is doing in both functions

Comment: @Peerox that's why you need to learn about scope; I added a link. Without the `return`, `signup_username` just vanishes as soon as you get out of the function, so we don't want to lose that information. Instead, we _return_ the values to the function caller.